# How to overlay date and time onto the corner of photos?

Tags: software, batch, time

Is there any utility which will read a photo's date and time from its EXIF data and embed it into the corner of the photo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are comfortable with command line tools from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), you can do something like this:

```
convert orig_image.jpg -gravity NorthWest -annotate 0 "%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]"  new_image.jpg
```

You can run this to batch process all your images.

**Details**

ImageMagick has an array of [command line tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php) to do different things with image. I'm using the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) tool here with `annotate` option to annotate a text on the converted image. There are whole bunch of other options that can be used to control font, color, shadow etc. Explaining all will be out of scope of the question, but you can take a look at [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/) doc.

`%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]` is a shortcut for:

```
identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]" <image_filename>
```

You can do something like: `identify -format "%[EXIF:*DATE*]" <image_filename>` to see what all date related strings are stored in exif.

Comment: What doe the timestamp actually look like? Is the font customizable? Color? Any shadow capabilities? Pretty cool command line, but it would be interesting to know more about how far its capabilities extend.

Comment: @Jon, i've edited my answer to add more details. I hope that answers all your question.

Comment: Yeah, ImageMagick in itself is very powerful and provides comprehensive set of tools to power someone's final step of workflow.

Answer (score 4):

Please check out http://jambula.sourceforge.net/ to batch insert shooting date/time/comment on a jpeg image in different formats and languages. A special feature is that the date stamp is lossless. It is supported on Linux and Mac also.

Comment: Would be a nice solution if it actually worked. Unfortunately it doesn't allow folders to be opened / selected in macOS 10.12.5 with the most recent release download from SF.

Comment: Works in 2020 in windows :)

Answer (score -1):

Since some cameras allow you to do this directly in-camera, you should check the menus and/or your manual.

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of my cameras (except a film P&S) has had this option, let alone for post processing (one might not want _only_ the stamped version of images). Also, this could only work for JPEGs.

Comment: My Nikon D5000 has it, and what's more it has 3 different settings for it: Date and Time, Date, and Day Counter. My answer was meant as a supplement to the other more PP-specific answers.

Comment: `s/most/some/`. I think Imre is right that _most_ don't.

Comment: You think or you know?

Comment: I have the strong, justified belief. I have not done a survey.