# Canon 600D image captured with date and time display?

Tags: canon-600d

I own a Canon EOS 600D camera. I need to know if it is possible to capture a picture along with the date and time. The image displayed after capture should also show the date and time of capture. I need to know what settings to be enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The camera will automatically record this information in the JPEG file, but not as a picture of numbers superimposed on the image. Some cameras have a feature to do this, but I don't think yours does. That's not necessarily bad, because doing it that way means you have part of the image covered by numbers and you can't get a clean image if you change your mind.

Instead, I suggest using the embedded, "hidden" metadata to add the timestamp using your computer after importing the photos. We have information on how to do this at [How to overlay date and time onto the corner of photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16953/how-to-overlay-date-and-time-onto-the-corner-of-photos)

Answer (score 3):

> The image displayed after capture should also show the date and time of capture. I need to know what settings to be enabled.

Whenever you take a photo, a number of pieces of information about the photo and camera settings are recorded in what's known as [*EXIF data*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format). Time and date, location, aperture and focal length, ISO, white balance, camera make and model, image resolution, and software version are just some of the values that may be found in an image's EXIF data. Most photo viewing and editing programs have a way to examine the EXIF data.

Answer (score 1):

In the preview mode you should click info button twice which displays the Image Size, the iso , the date and time of the image captured. If you click info again you will see the RGB displayed along with histogram. Clicking info again will take you back to the preview.